# Tkinter; get input from certain row/colomn

Tags: python, input, tkinter

(I'm using Python 3.5.)
I created a 5x5 grid and want to get the input from a certain row/colomn.
I've never used tkinter before and I'm new in programming.

I created the show button, so each time the user pushes it, I want the input to get printed. The problem is that, because of my two for loops, it only prints out the last element 44 because that's when the loop's finished.
How can I get ALL input without changing the for loops?

```
sudoku = Tk()

def show_entry_fields():
    print(name[r][i].get())


i = 0  
for i in range(0,5):  
    for r in range(0,5)  
        name[r][i] = Entry(sudoku)  
        name[r][i].grid(row=r,column=i)  

Button(sodoku, text='Quit', command=sodoku.quit).grid(row=5, column=1)
Button(sodoku, text='Show', command=show_entry_fields).grid(row=5, column=2)
sodoku.mainloop()
```

Comment: This is because you replace `name` each loop. This is no the full code so I can't specifically tell you how to solve this differently, but perhaps store the variable in a 2D list or a dictionary. For instance `my_data[i][r] = Entry(sodoku)`.

Comment: That's all I've written so far because I'm just hitting a wall with this. I tried your suggestion (if it was the way you ment it) but then the table didn't have any rows or colomns.

Answer (score 2):

> store the variable in a 2D list or a dictionary

---

```
# dictionary style  
root = {0:Tk()}
n = 5
m = 5
size = (n,m)

for i in range(1,n+1):
    for j in range(1,m+1):
        root[i,j] = Entry(sudoku)
        root[i,j].grid(row = i, column = j)
```

I'm used to use dictionary to store tkObject* (Frame, Grid, etc ...)

Indeed, its usefull when you want to get all objects or just the root, or just the first level of Frame.

In this case, root[1,*] will give you first line of your grid, when root[0] is the Tk instance.

---

In fact, you can do it like this too :

```
 # list style
 root = Tk()
 grid = [[Entry(sudoku).grid(row=i,column=j) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
```

I haven't test this code. So, be careful.

---

Test this :

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
grid = [[tk.Entry().grid(row=i,column=j) for i in range(5)] for j in range(5)]
input()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried this but the problem is, that it only returns me 'none', independently of the intend of the rows/columns.